Why doubling the operations within a loop does not double the CPU time?
I'd like to understand why the cpu time isn't doubled when performing twice as many operations within a loop in Fortran90. I wrote a small code like below,
program test

 integer  :: i, n
 real     :: time_begin, time_end
 real, dimension(50000000) :: x, y, z, a, b

 n = 50000000
 do i = 1, n
  x(i) = real(  i)
  y(i) = real(2*i)
  z(i) = real(3*i)
 end do

     a = 0.0
 
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
     a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " time1 = ", time_end - time_begin

     a = 0.0
     b = 0.0
     
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
    a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
    b(i) = b(i) + ( y(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " time2 = ", time_end - time_begin

 
end program test

and get the output like this:
time1 =   0.158164978
time2 =   0.230790973
The thing is that time2 is never close to twice time1 (2 x time1), and it is always around 50% more than time1 (1.5 x time1) although I'm asking the code to do twice as many operations in the loop. I've run the code many times, but I get the same thing (every time and on average).
Maybe the compiler (gfortran, gcc_10.2.0) is doing something to avoid doubling CPU time, but I can't find any clue on what it is doing. I'd appreciate if anyone could provide me with any clue. Thanks.
I've tried to change the operations into multiplications, and also separate the second loop into two loops (one for a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) ) and the other for b(i) = b(i) + ( y(i) + z(i) ) ), but the result is the same: time2 is never close to twice time1 (2 x time1), and it is always around 50% more than time1 (1.5 x time1).

Compilers do do clever things (far too clever for a comment), but even at the most naive, the loop isn't doing simply one or two things in the iteration: the naive compiler is also incrementing the loop index (i In this case) every iteration.  That means comparing the cost of three actions against two actions, not two actions against one action.

And it also has to load things from memory - in the above example z( i ) is used in both expressions in the second loop, and so less than twice as many loads need to be done

To elaborate on @IanBush comment, loading from memory (or storing to memory) has a significant cost compared to the very simple calculations that are performed in your loop. In your first loop for each iteration you have 3 loads, 2 additions, 1 store, that an "Arithmetic Intensity" equal to 2/(3+1)=0.5. In such a case, the transfers between the RAM and the CPU are likely the bottleneck. In your second loop you have 5 loads, 4 additions, 2 stores, that is an AI equal to 4/7=0.57: not a dramatic change, but nonetheless this can explain a part of what you are observing.

BTW, when posting about performances, it's very important to mention the compilation options you are using.

Thank you for your comment (BTW, I compiled it with just "gfortran xxx.f90" without specifying any options.) It makes sense. I increased the operations and observed consistent results: ~1.5 for 1 addition vs 2 additions ('three actions against two actions'), ~2.5 for 1 addition vs 4 addition (so, actually 5 actions against 2 actions), ~4.5 for 1 addition vs 8 additions (so, actually 9 actions against 2 actions),.

@PierU Thanks, but I'm not sure about effects of "Arithmetic Intensity" here, how it explains a part of the results. I'd like to try if there's a test that I can see its impact. Thanks.

Compiling without optimizations has little relevance to performance. Your question did make sense anyway and your curiosity reasoned, but for  future investigations of performance of various code variants it really makes little sense to not use compiler optimizations.

@VladimirFГероямслава, hmm, compiling this test with -O2 optimization will give a dumb 0. However, GNU Fortran (MacPorts gc13 13.3.0_1+stdlib_flag) 13.3.0 with -O optimization the second cycle, for some reason, will not be able to completely eliminate. Controversial advice (difficult to implement).

@Serge3leo The advice is perfectly fine, but the program must not just do useless irrelevant stuff that can be optimized away. At least print the result at the end. Otherwise the compiler can throw away everything, the program does not print anything that actually has to be computed. This has been discussed many times.

If you repeat the time measurement sections many times in your code.
test3.f90:
program test

 integer  :: i, n
 real     :: time_begin, time_end
 real, dimension(50000000) :: x, y, z, a, b

 n = 50000000
 do i = 1, n
  x(i) = real(  i)
  y(i) = real(2*i)
  z(i) = real(3*i)
 end do

     a = 0.0
 
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
     a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " time1 = ", time_end - time_begin

     a = 0.0
     b = 0.0
     
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
    a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
    b(i) = b(i) + ( y(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " time2 = ", time_end - time_begin

 
     a = 0.0
 
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
     a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " retry time1 = ", time_end - time_begin

     a = 0.0
     b = 0.0
     
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
    a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
    b(i) = b(i) + ( y(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " retry time2 = ", time_end - time_begin
 

     a = 0.0
 
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
     a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " retry2 time1 = ", time_end - time_begin

     a = 0.0
     b = 0.0
     
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
    a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
    b(i) = b(i) + ( y(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " retry2 time2 = ", time_end - time_begin


     a = 0.0
 
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
     a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " retry3 time1 = ", time_end - time_begin

     a = 0.0
     b = 0.0
     
 call cpu_time( time_begin )
  do i = 1, n
    a(i) = a(i) + ( x(i) + z(i) )
    b(i) = b(i) + ( y(i) + z(i) )
  end do
 call cpu_time( time_end )
 write(*,*) " retry3 time2 = ", time_end - time_begin


end program test

It turns out that sometimes the second cycle will be performed twice as slowly, and sometimes one and a half times.
(test.f90 - original test; test1.f90, test2.f90, test3.f90 - tests with duplicate code):
$ for t in test{,1,2,3}; do gfortran $t.f90 -o $t ; done
$ for t in test{,1,2,3}; do echo ./$t ; ./$t ; done
./test
  time1 =   0.215755999    
  time2 =   0.329641104    
./test1
  time1 =   0.206468999    
  time2 =   0.413877070    
  retry time1 =   0.198271036    
  retry time2 =   0.323944092    
./test2
  time1 =   0.204968989    
  time2 =   0.329955041    
  retry time1 =   0.197854996    
  retry time2 =   0.407590985    
  retry2 time1 =   0.200308084    
  retry2 time2 =   0.323467016    
./test3
  time1 =   0.252763033    
  time2 =   0.331092954    
  retry time1 =   0.206470013    
  retry time2 =   0.325465918    
  retry2 time1 =   0.198020935    
  retry2 time2 =   0.407527924    
  retry3 time1 =   0.198063850    
  retry3 time2 =   0.323588848 

If we compare the compiled machine code (assembly instructions), they will turn out to be identical.
$ for t in test{,1,2,3}; do gfortran -S $t.f90 -o $t.s ; done
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (MacPorts gcc13 13.3.0_1+stdlib_flag) 13.3.0
...
$ cpuid
...
Processor Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
...

Probably, the reason for the different performance of the same instruction sequences is Power Mode settings. Or alignment in memory. Or cache algorithm. But this is inaccurate and requires more detailed analysis using: Linux perf, Xcode Instruments, Intel VTune or similar tools.
The main performance ratio of cycles with only array a and with two arrays a and b ≈2/3 (0.67) is most likely explained by modern dual-channel memory. Since the size of each array is about 200 MB, they do not fit into the cache, then performance is determined by memory exchange. A loop with one array a, reads 3 arrays and writes 1 at each iteration, but writing is combined with reading. A loop with two arrays a and b, reads 5 arrays at each iteration (+ 1 reading from the cache) and writes 2, but writing is combined with reading. If the memory were single-channel, then the expected ratio would be ≈3/5 (0.6), but for dual-channel memory, one can expect ≈(3+1)/(5+1) ≈2/3 (0,67).
